# Issue with Forge Viewer Element Properties

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

We're encountering an issue in our application that involves the implementation of the Forge Viewer.

In our app, we use the Forge Viewer to highlight elements using dbIds. The process starts with the Revit element Id in the backend. We retrieve the externalId and create a map of externalId to dbId using the "https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-query-POST/" API.

The problem arises when the API fails to provide the dbId for some elements in certain models. However, we double-checked and found that the same elements yield dbIds in the frontend using the "viewer.search" method.

We're puzzled by this discrepancy and seek your assistance in understanding why this is happening and finding a solution.

NOP_VIEWERS[1].search('3183335', (data)=> {console.log(data)}, (err)=> {console.log(err)}, ["ElementId"], {searchHidden: true}) We did this to check element is present or not, and here we are getting dbIds but for the same element we are not getting dbId with Forge properties API.